# ¿Como puedo evadir una variable vacia en google tag manager?

Tags: javascript, php, get, google-api

Buenas gente la cosa es que me gustaria saber como llega la info de un parametro vacio y como poder hacer comparaciones en google tag manager con el.

Ejemplo:

> /?offer=3817&source=1&sub1=&utm_source=1&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=v6&utm_content=0&cid=

Si estos son los parametros get como llega el valor de cid a google tag manager porque no llega como indefinido y no se como realizar una comparacion con ese valor.

[image: Me gustaria poder hacer algo asi que el cid sea distinto de vacio]

Comment: Y, ¿por qué se genera vacío? ¿de dónde vienen tus datos? ¿por qué no cuidas allí que no se genera nada vacío?

Comment: @A.Cedano es simplemente para poder lanzar el script si el dato entra asi cid=
que ahora mismo no lo hace, pero a la vez quiero que si de verdad tiene un valor no lance el script de googletag manager

Comment: No entiendo. Conviene que pongas el código con el que estás trabajando pulsando en [edit].

Comment: Sencillo si el cid se pasa vacio google tag manager debe añadir el script si no esta vacio no debe y si ni siquiera esta en la url si debe lanzar el script

Comment: Ya, pero ¿desde qué contexto, y mediante qué código se decide eso?

Comment: No tienes la posibilidad de usar regex para los parámetros? Pues ponle un patrón que busque... nada: `^$` y listo. Siempre que tenga un valor, ese patrón no hará match, siempre que esté vacío, si

Answer (score 0):

En GTM para chequear si una variable no está definida es tan simple como chequear si es igual a `undefined`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo acabo de chequear y funciona perfecto.

Espero que sirva. Saludos!